# Keep on having StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for this part

Tags: java

I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for this part of the code.
What could be the reason? contact is declared as String

```
    do{

        System.out.print("Contact Number (01X-XXXXXXX) :");
        contact = scan.next();
        if(!phNumValidation(contact)){
            System.out.println("Invalid Phone Number. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }while(!phNumValidation(contact) || contact.length() < 11);
```

this is the method for phone number validation

```
public static boolean phNumValidation(String contact){
    boolean valid = true;
    String dash = contact.substring(3, 4);
    if(contact.length() == 11){
        valid = true;
        valid = contact.startsWith("01");
        valid = dash.matches("-");
    }
    else{
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: What is contact? What is phNumValidation? With this information we cant help you at anything. Please give detailed information.

Comment: Your `substring` is not working on Strings which have lower than 4 characters.

Comment: What input gives you the exception?

Comment: you can try `contact.match(regex)`

Comment: less than 4 characters or digits

Comment: So you're checking whether the fourth character of a string with less than four characters is a hyphen?  And you want to know why you get an index out of bounds exception?

Comment: I'm still a student starting in Java. Pardon me for making seemingly idiotic mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

move the contact.length<11 validation on the left-side of the or (talking about the while statement).

Otherwise you are entering into the phNumValidation even with less than 11chars contacts. And that method is not prepared for that.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because you tend to pass `contact` of `length <=4` to `phNumValidation` function and do a substring without checking the length first. Below code will not throw any exception as length would be checked first. While loop would also need not call the function again.

```
  boolean valid = false;
  do{
        System.out.print("Contact Number (01X-XXXXXXX) :");
        contact = scan.next();
        if(!phNumValidation(contact)){
            System.out.println("Invalid Phone Number. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("");
        }else{
            valid = true;
        }


    }while(!valid);


public static boolean phNumValidation(String contact){
    boolean valid = true;

    if(contact.length() == 11){
    String dash = contact.substring(3, 4);
    valid = true;
        valid = contact.startsWith("01");
        valid = dash.matches("-");
    }
    else{
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's time for you to use regular expressions, for example this is how my `validation` method would look like.

```
public static boolean phNumValidation(String contact){
    return contact.matches("01\\d-\\d{7}");
}
```

This method validates length, format all at once.